# add parameters inside url

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to build some function that read a url from txt file, then save it to some variable, then add some values inside the url between another values

example of the url: `https://domains.livedns.co.il/API/DomainsAPI.asmx/NewDomain?UserName=apidemo@livedns.co.il&Password=demo`

lets say i want to inject some values between UserName and Password and save it into file again and use it later.

i started to write the function and play with urllib parser but i still doesnt understand how to do that.

what i tried until now:

```
def dlastpurchase():
    if os.path.isfile("livednsurl.txt"):
        apikeyfile = open("livednsurl.txt", "r")
        apikey = apikeyfile.read()
        url_parse = urlsplit(apikey)
        print(url_parse.geturl())
dlastpurchase()
```

Thanks in advance for every tip and help

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: i edit the post with the code i tried

Comment: The parameters in a URL are not ordered.  You can add your parameters to the end, by appending `&choice=7&size=xl`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use fancy tools to do that. Just split the url based on "?" Character. Then, split the second part based on "&" character. Add your new params to the list you have, and merge them with the base url you get.

```py
url = "https://domains.livedns.co.il/API/DomainsAPI.asmx/NewDomain?UserName=apidemo@livedns.co.il&Password=demo"

base, params = url.split("?")
params = params.split("&")
params.insert(2, "new_user=yololo&new_passwd=hololo")
for param in params:
    base += param + "&"
base = base.strip("&")
print(base)
```

I did it like this since you asked for inserting to a specific location. But url params are not depends on the order, so you can just append at the end of the url for ease. Or, you can edit the parameters from the list I show.

Comment: if u can show me some example ill thank u

Answer (score 1):

A little bit more complex example that I believe you will find interesting and also enjoy improving it (while it takes care of some scenarios, it might be lacking in some). Also functional to enable reuse in other cases. Here we go

assuming we have a text file, named 'urls.txt' that contains this url
`https://domains.livedns.co.il/API/DomainsAPI.asmx/NewDomain?UserName=apidemo@livedns.co.il&Password=demo`

```
from os import error
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs, urlunparse
filename = 'urls.txt'
```

function to parse the url and return its query parameters as well as the url object, which will be used to reconstruct the url later on

```
def parse_url(url):
    """parse a given url and return its query parameters

    Args:
        url (string): url string to parse 
    Returns:
        parsed (tupple): the tupple object returned by urlparse
        query_parameters (dictionary): dictionary containing the query parameters as keys
    """
    try :
        # parse the url and get the queries parameters from there
        parsed = urlparse(url)
        # parse the queries and return the dictionary containing them
        query_result = parse_qs(parsed.query)
        return (query_result, parsed)
    except(error): 
        print('something failed !!!')
        print(error)
        return False
```

function to add a new query parameter or to replace an existing one

```
def insert_or_replace_word(query_dic, word,value):
    """Insert a value for the query parameters of a url

    Args:
        query_dic (object): the dictionary containing the query parameters
        word (string): the query parameter to replace or insert values for
        value (string): the value to insert or use as replacement
    Returns:
        result (string):the result of the insertion or replacement
    """
    try:
        query_dic[word] = value
        return query_dic
    except (error):
        print('Something went wrong {0}'.format(error))
```

function to format the query parameter and get them ready to reconstruct the new  url

```
def format_query_strings(query_dic):
    """format the final query dictionaries ready to be used to construct a new url and construct the new url

    Args:
        query_dic (dictionary): final query dictionary after insertion or update
    """
    final_string = ''
    for key, value in query_dic.items():
        #unfortunatly, query params from parse_qs are in list, so remove them before creating the final string
        if type(value) == list:
            query_string = '{0}={1}'.format(key, value[0])
            final_string += '{0}&'.format(query_string)
        else:
            query_string = '{0}={1}'.format(key, value)
            final_string += '{0}&'.format(query_string)
            
    # this is to remove any extra & inserted at the end of the loop above
    if final_string.endswith('&'):
        final_string = final_string[:len(final_string)-1]
    return final_string
```

we check out everything works by reading in text file, performing above operation and then saving the new url to a new file

```
with open(filename) as url:
    lines = url.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        query_params,parsed = parse_url(line)
        new_query_dic = insert_or_replace_word(query_params,'UserName','newUsername')
        final = format_query_strings(new_query_dic)
        #here you have to pass an iterable of lenth 6 in order to reconstruct the url
        new_url_object = [parsed.scheme,parsed.netloc,parsed.path,parsed.params,final,parsed.fragment]    
        #this reconstructs the new url
        new_url = urlunparse(new_url_object)
        #create a new file and append the link inside of it
        with open('new_urls.txt', 'a') as new_file:
            new_file.writelines(new_c)
            new_file.write('\n')
```